# How can I extract mid-point positions per entry name from a data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this file:

```
chromosome   start     end       name short.name start.gene  middle
chr8 7447754 7447754  SPAG11B_1    SPAG11B    7447754 7447754
chr8 7462707 7462707  SPAG11B_2    SPAG11B    7447754 7462707
chr8 7463443 7463443  SPAG11B_3    SPAG11B    7447754 7463443
chr8 7470308 7470308 DEFB104B_1   DEFB104B    7470308 7470308
chr8 7475011 7475011 DEFB104B_2   DEFB104B    7470308 7475011
chr8 7896474 7896474   DEFB4A_2     DEFB4A    7894677 7896474
```

Which I load into an R dataframe with:

```
> df <- read.table("a", header=T)
> df
  chromosome   start     end       name short.name start.gene  middle
1       chr8 7447754 7447754  SPAG11B_1    SPAG11B    7447754 7447754
2       chr8 7462707 7462707  SPAG11B_2    SPAG11B    7447754 7462707
3       chr8 7463443 7463443  SPAG11B_3    SPAG11B    7447754 7463443
4       chr8 7470308 7470308 DEFB104B_1   DEFB104B    7470308 7470308
5       chr8 7475011 7475011 DEFB104B_2   DEFB104B    7470308 7475011
6       chr8 7896474 7896474   DEFB4A_2     DEFB4A    7894677 7896474
```

I now need to extract a vector containing the point at the middle of the start and end positions of each unique `short.name`. For example, the short name `SPAG11B` has three entries, with the first `start` at `7447754` and the last `end` at `7463443`. So, for this name, I would want to get `0.5*(7447754+7463443)` which is `7455598`. And the same for all other `short.name` values:

```
7455598 ## SPAG11B:  0.5*(7447754+7463443)
7472660 ## DEFB104B: 0.5*(7470308+7475011)
7896474 ## DEFB4A:   0.5*(7896474+7896474)
```

The final result for the example above would be a vector with these values:

```
7455598, 7472660, 7896474
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can group by 'short.name', get the `first` and `last` element of 'middle', sum it and multiply by `0.5`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(short.name) %>%
  summarise(middle = 0.5 *(first(middle) + last(middle))) %>%
  pull(middle)
  #[1] 7472660 7896474 7455598
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(chromosome = c("chr8", "chr8", "chr8", "chr8", 
"chr8", "chr8"), start = c(7447754L, 7462707L, 7463443L, 7470308L, 
7475011L, 7896474L), end = c(7447754L, 7462707L, 7463443L, 7470308L, 
7475011L, 7896474L), name = c("SPAG11B_1", "SPAG11B_2", "SPAG11B_3", 
"DEFB104B_1", "DEFB104B_2", "DEFB4A_2"), short.name = c("SPAG11B", 
"SPAG11B", "SPAG11B", "DEFB104B", "DEFB104B", "DEFB4A"), 
start.gene = c(7447754L, 
7447754L, 7447754L, 7470308L, 7470308L, 7894677L), middle = c(7447754L, 
7462707L, 7463443L, 7470308L, 7475011L, 7896474L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the package `data.table` as follows:

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
chromosome   start     end       name short.name start.gene  middle
chr8 7447754 7447754  SPAG11B_1    SPAG11B    7447754 7447754
chr8 7462707 7462707  SPAG11B_2    SPAG11B    7447754 7462707
chr8 7463443 7463443  SPAG11B_3    SPAG11B    7447754 7463443
chr8 7470308 7470308 DEFB104B_1   DEFB104B    7470308 7470308
chr8 7475011 7475011 DEFB104B_2   DEFB104B    7470308 7475011
chr8 7896474 7896474   DEFB4A_2     DEFB4A    7894677 7896474")

library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, 0.5 * (start[1] + end[.N]), short.name]$V1
# 7455599 7472660 7896474
```